# Tomcat 6, hibernate, oracle 11 logon denied

Tags: java, oracle, tomcat, c3p0, ora-01017

Project on eclipse 3.5, wicket, spring, hibernate, oracle 11 database and Tomcat 6 (Its a sample from book "wicket in action"). In this project I can not connect to database. 
Can anybody help to fix it?
That is log:

```
25.06.2010 13:58:32 org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_13\bin;.;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\Program Files\PC Connectivity Solution\;c:\ruby\bin;C:\Program Files\Borland\Delphi7\Bin;C:\Program Files\Borland\Delphi7\Projects\Bpl\;c:\oracle\ora92\bin;C:\Program Files\Oracle\jre\1.3.1\bin;C:\Program Files\Oracle\jre\1.1.8\bin;C:\oracle\ora92\REPORT60.817\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;D:\app\D_Unusov\product\11.1.0\client_1;D:\app\D_Unusov\product\11.1.0\client_1\bin;C:\Program Files\VisualSVN Server\bin\;C:\Program Files\VisualSVN\bin;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_13\bin\";C:\ruby\bin\nclude-dependencies\bin\;C:\Program Files\apache-maven\bin
25.06.2010 13:58:32 org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.server:pos' did not find a matching property.
25.06.2010 13:58:32 org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol init
INFO: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
25.06.2010 13:58:32 org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 689 ms
25.06.2010 13:58:32 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService start
INFO: Starting service Catalina
25.06.2010 13:58:32 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.26
25.06.2010 13:58:33 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
INFO  - ContextLoader              - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
INFO  - XmlWebApplicationContext   - Refreshing org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext@17494c8: display name [Root WebApplicationContext]; startup date [Fri Jun 25 13:58:33 UZT 2010]; root of context hierarchy
INFO  - XmlBeanDefinitionReader    - Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [applicationContext.xml]
INFO  - XmlWebApplicationContext   - Bean factory for application context [org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext@17494c8]: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@174219d
INFO  - pertyPlaceholderConfigurer - Loading properties file from class path resource [application.properties]
INFO  - DefaultListableBeanFactory - Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@174219d: defining beans [placeholderConfig,dataSource,sessionFactory,transactionManager,org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator,org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0,org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor#0,org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor,wicketApplication]; root of factory hierarchy
INFO  - MLog                       - MLog clients using log4j logging.
INFO  - C3P0Registry               - Initializing c3p0-0.9.1.2 [built 21-May-2007 15:04:56; debug? true; trace: 10]
INFO  - Version                    - Hibernate Annotations 3.3.0.GA
INFO  - Environment                - Hibernate 3.2.1
INFO  - Environment                - hibernate.properties not found
INFO  - Environment                - Bytecode provider name : cglib
INFO  - Environment                - using JDK 1.4 java.sql.Timestamp handling
INFO  - AnnotationBinder           - Binding entity from annotated class: tj.eskhata.pos.domain.User
INFO  - EntityBinder               - Bind entity tj.eskhata.pos.domain.User on table users
INFO  - AnnotationConfiguration    - Hibernate Validator not found: ignoring
INFO  - notationSessionFactoryBean - Building new Hibernate SessionFactory
INFO  - AnnotationConfiguration    - Hibernate Validator not found: ignoring
INFO  - ConnectionProviderFactory  - Initializing connection provider: org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider
INFO  - stractPoolBackedDataSource - Initializing c3p0 pool... com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource [ java.beans.IntrospectionException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException [numThreadsAwaitingCheckoutDefaultUser] ]
WARN  - JDBCExceptionReporter      - SQL Error: 1017, SQLState: 72000
ERROR - JDBCExceptionReporter      - ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied

WARN  - SettingsFactory            - Could not obtain connection metadata
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:439)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:388)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:381)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.processError(T4CTTIfun.java:564)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.processError(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:431)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:436)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:186)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.doOAUTH(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:366)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.doOAUTH(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:752)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:359)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:531)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:221)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:32)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:503)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnection(DriverManagerDataSource.java:119)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:143)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:132)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager.initializeAutomaticTestTable(C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager.java:772)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager.createPooledConnectionPool(C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager.java:696)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager.getPool(C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager.java:257)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager.getPool(C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager.java:271)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.java:128)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider.getConnection(LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider.java:82)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:76)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:2006)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1289)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.buildSessionFactory(AnnotationConfiguration.java:915)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.newSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:814)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:732)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.AbstractSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractSessionFactoryBean.java:211)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1369)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:473)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:380)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:264)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:261)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:164)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:423)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:728)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:380)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:255)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:199)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:45)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:3972)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4467)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:785)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:519)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:581)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
INFO  - Dialect                    - Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect
INFO  - TransactionFactoryFactory  - Transaction strategy: org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SpringTransactionFactory
INFO  - actionManagerLookupFactory - No TransactionManagerLookup configured (in JTA environment, use of read-write or transactional second-level cache is not recommended)
INFO  - SettingsFactory            - Automatic flush during beforeCompletion(): disabled
INFO  - SettingsFactory            - Automatic session close at end of transaction: disabled
INFO  - SettingsFactory            - Scrollable result sets: disabled
INFO  - SettingsFactory            - JDBC3 getGeneratedKeys(): disabled
INFO  - SettingsFactory            - Connection release mode: auto
INFO  - SettingsFactory            - Default batch fetch size: 1
INFO  - SettingsFactory            - Generate SQL with comments: disabled
INFO  - SettingsFactory            - Order SQL updates by primary key: disabled
INFO  - SettingsFactory            - Query translator: org.hibernate.hql.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
INFO  - ASTQueryTranslatorFactory  - Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
INFO  - SettingsFactory            - Query language substitutions: {}
INFO  - SettingsFactory            - JPA-QL strict compliance: disabled
INFO  - SettingsFactory            - Second-level cache: enabled
INFO  - SettingsFactory            - Query cache: disabled
INFO  - SettingsFactory            - Cache provider: org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider
INFO  - SettingsFactory            - Optimize cache for minimal puts: disabled
INFO  - SettingsFactory            - Structured second-level cache entries: disabled
INFO  - SettingsFactory            - Statistics: disabled
INFO  - SettingsFactory            - Deleted entity synthetic identifier rollback: disabled
INFO  - SettingsFactory            - Default entity-mode: pojo
INFO  - SessionFactoryImpl         - building session factory
INFO  - essionFactoryObjectFactory - Not binding factory to JNDI, no JNDI name configured
INFO  - ibernateTransactionManager - Using DataSource [com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource [ java.beans.IntrospectionException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException [numThreadsAwaitingCheckoutDefaultUser] ]] of Hibernate SessionFactory for HibernateTransactionManager
INFO  - ContextLoader              - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 8218 ms
INFO  - Application                - [PosApplication] init: Wicket JMX initializer
INFO  - Initializer                - registering Wicket mbeans with server com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer@1c5c1
INFO  - Application                - [PosApplication] init: DevUtils DebugBar Initializer
INFO  - Application                - [PosApplication] init: Wicket core library initializer
INFO  - RequestListenerInterface   - registered listener interface [RequestListenerInterface name=IBehaviorListener, method=public abstract void org.apache.wicket.behavior.IBehaviorListener.onRequest()]
INFO  - RequestListenerInterface   - registered listener interface [RequestListenerInterface name=IBehaviorListener, method=public abstract void org.apache.wicket.behavior.IBehaviorListener.onRequest()]
INFO  - RequestListenerInterface   - registered listener interface [RequestListenerInterface name=IFormSubmitListener, method=public abstract void org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.IFormSubmitListener.onFormSubmitted()]
INFO  - RequestListenerInterface   - registered listener interface [RequestListenerInterface name=IFormSubmitListener, method=public abstract void org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.IFormSubmitListener.onFormSubmitted()]
INFO  - RequestListenerInterface   - registered listener interface [RequestListenerInterface name=ILinkListener, method=public abstract void org.apache.wicket.markup.html.link.ILinkListener.onLinkClicked()]
INFO  - RequestListenerInterface   - registered listener interface [RequestListenerInterface name=ILinkListener, method=public abstract void org.apache.wicket.markup.html.link.ILinkListener.onLinkClicked()]
INFO  - RequestListenerInterface   - registered listener interface [RequestListenerInterface name=IOnChangeListener, method=public abstract void org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.IOnChangeListener.onSelectionChanged()]
INFO  - RequestListenerInterface   - registered listener interface [RequestListenerInterface name=IOnChangeListener, method=public abstract void org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.IOnChangeListener.onSelectionChanged()]
INFO  - RequestListenerInterface   - registered listener interface [RequestListenerInterface name=IRedirectListener, method=public abstract void org.apache.wicket.IRedirectListener.onRedirect()]
INFO  - RequestListenerInterface   - registered listener interface [RequestListenerInterface name=IRedirectListener, method=public abstract void org.apache.wicket.IRedirectListener.onRedirect()]
INFO  - RequestListenerInterface   - registered listener interface [RequestListenerInterface name=IResourceListener, method=public abstract void org.apache.wicket.IResourceListener.onResourceRequested()]
INFO  - RequestListenerInterface   - registered listener interface [RequestListenerInterface name=IResourceListener, method=public abstract void org.apache.wicket.IResourceListener.onResourceRequested()]
INFO  - RequestListenerInterface   - registered listener interface [RequestListenerInterface name=IActivePageBehaviorListener, method=public abstract void org.apache.wicket.behavior.IBehaviorListener.onRequest()]
INFO  - RequestListenerInterface   - registered listener interface [RequestListenerInterface name=IActivePageBehaviorListener, method=public abstract void org.apache.wicket.behavior.IBehaviorListener.onRequest()]
INFO  - Application                - [PosApplication] init: org.apache.wicket.velocity.Initializer@5bd978
INFO  - Initializer                - Initialized Velocity successfully
INFO  - Application                - [PosApplication] init: Wicket extensions initializer
INFO  - WebApplication             - [PosApplication] Started Wicket version 1.4.8 in development mode
********************************************************************
*** WARNING: Wicket is running in DEVELOPMENT mode.              ***
***                               ^^^^^^^^^^^                    ***
*** Do NOT deploy to your live server(s) without changing this.  ***
*** See Application#getConfigurationType() for more information. ***
********************************************************************
25.06.2010 13:58:42 org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start
INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
25.06.2010 13:58:42 org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket init
INFO: JK: ajp13 listening on /0.0.0.0:8009
25.06.2010 13:58:42 org.apache.jk.server.JkMain start
INFO: Jk running ID=0 time=0/15  config=null
25.06.2010 13:58:42 org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 9640 ms
```

and this is  config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:jndi="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jndi"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.0.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx  
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jndi 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jndi/spring-jndi.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-2.0.xsd">    

    <bean id="placeholderConfig"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="location">
            <value>classpath:application.properties</value>
        </property>
        <property name="systemPropertiesModeName">
            <value>SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClass">
            <value>${jdbc.driver}</value>
        </property>
        <property name="jdbcUrl">
            <value>jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.7.225:1521:MTSOTEST</value>
        </property>
        <property name="user">
            <value>mta</value>
        </property>
        <property name="password">
            <value>mta</value>
        </property>
        <property name="minPoolSize">
            <value>${c3p0.minPoolSize}</value>
        </property>
        <property name="maxPoolSize">
            <value>${c3p0.maxPoolSize}</value>
        </property>
        <property name="checkoutTimeout">
            <value>20000</value>
        </property>
        <property name="maxIdleTime">
            <value>${c3p0.maxIdleTime}</value>
        </property>
        <property name="idleConnectionTestPeriod">
            <value>${c3p0.idleConnectionTestPeriod}</value>
        </property>
        <property name="automaticTestTable">
            <value>${c3p0.automaticTestTable}</value>
        </property>
    </bean>


    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>tj.eskhata.pos.domain.User</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager"
            class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>
    <tx:annotation-driven />

    <bean id="wicketApplication"
        class="tj.eskhata.pos.PosApplication">
    </bean>


</beans>
```

I wrote a test console application to test jdbc and it works well:

```
package MyTest;

import java.sql.*;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {            
              Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");          
              Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:mta/mta@192.168.7.225:1521:MTSOTEST" );            
              Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();           
              ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM users");                        
              for (int j = 1; j <= rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount(); j++) {
                System.out.print(rs.getMetaData().getColumnName(j) + "\t");
              }
              System.out.println();
              while (rs.next()) {
                for (int j = 1; j <= rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount(); j++) {
                 System.out.print(rs.getObject(j) + "\t");
                }
                System.out.println();
              }           
              rs.close();
              stmt.close();
              conn.close();
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Through eclipse's Data Source Explorer I can connect to that database with the same jdbc.

Answer (score 2):

This message provides you with an useful info:

```
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied
```

First check what is described in [the following page](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_01017.htm) and try again.

Also check that in your Spring configuration files you  didn't misspell some property. Now that I think about it, this property `<property name="user">` shouldn't in fact be `<property name="username"`>. Check your driver.

Comment: I have checked as <property name="username"> but error report have not changed.??

Comment: @Daler: Looked up the API for com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource, the property is in fact "user". My hunch was wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Solution was because of Tomcat have not syncronized the project with that it was runing, thanks dpb for your answers.